# Why does the differential equation $y' = y + 1$ have solution $y(x) = Ce^x - 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was watching a video on differential equations for a class that I'm taking. I took calculus so long ago that I can't seem to figure why the differential equation  $y' = y + 1$ has solution $y(x) = Ce^x - 1$.

Comment: so you dont know how to solve diff.equation?

Comment: I couldn't solve this particular one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y+1$$
$$\frac{dy}{y+1}=dx$$
$$\ln(y+1)=x+a$$
$$y+1=e^{x+a}=ce^x$$

Comment: you should have to show integration in 2nd line

Comment: That simple... Thank you :) I get it now!

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to plug in $y(x) = ce^x-1$ back into the differential equation and see if the differential equation is satisfied. To actually, derive the solution, note that
$$y' = y + 1 \implies (y+1)' = (y+1) \implies y+1 = ce^x \implies y = ce^x-1$$

Comment: I couldn't follow why you simply switched y' to (y+1)'

Comment: @TheSunken Note that $(y+1)' = y'+1' = y'$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=y+1$, then $u'=y'$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
y'&=y+1\\
u'&=u\\
\frac{du}{dx}&=u\\
\frac{du}{u}&=dx\\
\int \frac{du}{u}&=\int\ dx\\
\ln u&=x+K\\
\ln (y+1)&=x+K\\
\cdots&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$